# Wifi interface for windows

Tags: python, windows, networking, scapy, packet-sniffers

This ARP spoofing script is taken from the book "Black hat python" by Justin Seitz (2014). Since it is written for Linux, how could you find the right interface if you were to use it on Windows?

```
from scapy.all import *
import os, sys, threading, signal

interface = "wlan0"

(...)

# set our interface
conf.iface = interface

# turn off output
conf.verb = 0

print(("[*] Setting up %s" % interface))

(...)

try:
    print(("[*] Starting program for %d packets" % packet_count))
    bpf_filter = "ip host %s" % target_ip
    packets = sniff(count=packet_count, filter=bpf_filter, iface=interface)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried it on Windows? It should work, used libraries are cross platform

Comment: I tried, but got a huge error message, with the bottom line _ValueError: Unknown network interface 'wlan0'_, but if not wlan0, whats the correct interface then for a windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, the scapy libraries detects your interfaces and store them in an IFACES variable.

After having installed/downloaded scapy, start the scapy shell (command: `scapy` if it you have downloaded it manually, `run_scapy.bat`) and type `IFACES`

It will give you the list of the installed interfaces. You can then either use

- `interface = "[The full interface name as shown in scapy]"`
- `interface = IFACES.dev_from_index([the index of the interface as shown by scapy])`

If you don’t have other interfaces than the WiFi one, you can even use `interface = conf.iface`

Comment: That worked perfect for the interfaces, thanks. Do you also know where in the script I'd have to start, if I'd want to drop intercepted packets?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by drop. If this answer has helped you, please mark it as accepted and start a new question :)

Comment: No scapy can’t stop packets from reaching their destination. It can only sniff them. Try using netfilterqueue